# Occasional CSS Google font corruption?

Tags: css, fonts

I am sometimes encountering font corruptions as shown in the image below, when using Open Sans (from Google Fonts) in CSS (as taken wholesale from http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700):

**Corrupted**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmqJL.png

**Non-Corrupted**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2sWUB.png

Note that some of the text is rendered fine, while other text of the same markup, like the second line, gets garbled. It doesn't seem like a kerning issue because the symbols rendered are entirely different.

I've noticed that every lowercase character (and some uppercase ones) moves forward by one? (e.g. `h` becomes `i` but with the letter spacing of `h`, resulting in ugly "kerning")  I think it may be because the forward slash (`/`) is used, but I've also replicated the issue in lines without the slash, but what could cause this strange issue?

The problem usually resolves by refreshing multiple times (both Ctrl-F5 or normal F5 don't yield any noticeable differences, nor does disabling cache via Dev Tools), but occasionally comes back with no discernable pattern.

To clarify, I do not have the font installed locally on my computer, so the woff2 file is requested from Google's servers. Both corrupted and non-corrupted text can be reproduced regardless of whether the browser requests a fresh file (HTTP 200) or from the cache (HTTP 304).

I have also encountered this problem before using another Google font (Lato), which I did not take much notice of at that point in time.

I'm not sure if this issue is a browser issue (I'm using Google Chrome 43.0.2357.125) or an issue with the font itself? Does anyone else also face this issue as well?

Comment: Why don't you base 64 encode/embed the font? You can do it [here](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator), just check `Base64 Encode` (and you need only woff).

Comment: @skobaljic Wouldn't this result in a unecessarily large CSS file, and considering that Open Sans is a pretty common font, I was banking on the fact that other users would have this in their cache already thus eliminating any additional overhead. Besides, would encoding it solve such issues?

Comment: Could it be that his happens after updating the browser, but not restarting?

Comment: @lxer nope, just restarted Chrome (twice actually)

Comment: Browser will cache your CSS once loaded, so it is same. You cannot guarantee what kind of code will Google serve, but if you embed it, than you will know. I would not care about 100kb more on first load, but I would care if browser does not render the font correctly. Btw, 300=light, 400=normal, 700=bold, what is 600 for?

Comment: @skobaljic 600 is semi-bold

Comment: You can test your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/g2c59bcw/).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before, but never thought about the reason being google. Could be though.

Instead of requesting all the files from googles server, why not serve them from your own server? 
Just download the `.woff2` and `.woff` files and include them in your css.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't address the issue of why this happens or how to prevent it, if I download the same woff2 file it can still appear corrupted nonetheless (if the issue is about the source font). Moreover considering Open Sans is a pretty common font, requesting it from Google's servers would allow other users to serve it from their cache and thus eliminating additional HTTP overhead.

Comment: yes, but the overhead would not make much difference. The use of the long filename tells me they use a unique string for each time it is included in a website (which then can be used for tracking traffic/users?), so that would reduce the caching benefit. When you serve the .woff files yourself at least you know fonts.google didnt corrupt the file.

Comment: agreed that the overhead isn't much, though the long filename has been consistent (I actually embed the css with the font face URLs and I've compared it, it's the same). Still don't know what's the issue though.

Comment: You cannot tell `if I download the same woff2 file it can still appear corrupted nonetheless`, because you haven't tried it. In my experience all Google fonts troubles are solved the mentioned way: Compile those fonts and embed them on your website. Please try the suggestions you got here.

Comment: @skobaljic alright... did that and it's the same result. still having the occasional corruption. I often embed the Google fonts (and external resources for that matter) on my websites, such as serving sites on Intranets. but for this particular project I didn't see a need to. Nevertheless, still didn't work. I'm only concerned that other client computers may be showing the same thing.

Comment: then it must be your browser.